# iOS JSON request

Tags: ios, json, request

I have an app making a request to a JSON on a server to fetch some data . All works fine until 
the value for a field in the JSON has the `null` value . Then the app crashes . 
So I get the data , put it in a NSDictionary , and then access all the values in that dictionary . I've tried with those `if()` statements but still , if the value is `null` , the app crashes .

```
            if([item valueForKey:@"title"]!=NULL)
            [sbcvItem setTitle:[item valueForKey:@"title"]];
            if([item valueForKey:@"desc"]!=NULL)
            [sbcvItem setDesc:[item valueForKey:@"desc"]];
            if([item valueForKey:@"url"]!=NULL)
            [sbcvItem setUrl:[item valueForKey:@"url"]];
```

Any suggestion is welcome .

Comment: Which message produces when it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `NSDictionary` nor `NSArray` can store `nil` (or `NULL`) as a value.  Instead, we use a placeholder object.  That placeholder object is a singleton of class `NSNull`, and you get a pointer to it using `[NSNull null]`.  So you need to test like this:

```
if ([item objectForKey:@"title"] != [NSNull null])
    [sbcvItem setTitle:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `nil`, not `NULL`.

I suggest you inspect the values of `item` by setting a breakpoint in the debugger. Perhaps `item` itself is `nil`?

Comment: found it .. it was ``!=[NSNull null]``

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you getting from the json parser. usually you getting string value for null objects, for example "< null>", in this case your if should be:

```
if(![[item valueForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
        [sbcvItem setTitle:[item valueForKey:@"title"]];
...
```

in case you actually getting nil object then you can try:

```
if(![item valueForKey:@"title"])
        [sbcvItem setTitle:[item valueForKey:@"title"]];
...
```

to make sure what you have inside the dictionary you can nslog it.